# Linux - Closing screen session terminates process

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I am new to this so I apologize if I am using the wrong terms.

I am using Linux and am connected to my school workstation using the ssh function. If I run a program and I close the terminal the program stops. I read on ask ubuntu that I should use the screen function. However, when I close the screen I get an error and the process stops running. I can still reconnect to the screen.

```
linux screen XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:11.0"       after 4570 requests (4570 known processed) with 192 events remaining.
```

Comment: @Melebius You are right, thank you ! I was using matplotlib to save my figures and had to first disable the display https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713279/calling-pylab-savefig-without-display-in-ipython

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`screen` is intended for command-line applications but you seem to be using it with a GUI application according to your error message: Command-line applications should not interact with the [X server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Software_architecture).

Avoid running GUI applications from `screen` or use another approach, e.g. [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing).